# save command output to variable in bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to save the output of a `rsnapshot` command to a variable, and then later use that output. The variable seems empty, however.

Here's the script. Modified for debugging.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Run the command `rsnapshot daily`, and show results
echo "Making backup on USB drive attached to nas."
echo "running command 'rsnapshot -v daily'..."
rsnapshotresult=$( { rsnapshot -v daily; } )
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "rsnapshotdaily.sh error"
    echo $rsnapshotresult
    echo "done"
fi
```

Now, I run this script (file `rsnapshotdaily.sh`) on the command line. The output in the terminal:

```
[~] # /folder/rsnapshotdaily.sh
Making backup on USB drive attached to nas.
running command 'rsnapshot -v daily'...
Could not open logfile /share/USBDisk1/rsnapshotlog for writing
Do you have write permission for this file?
rsnapshotdaily.sh error

done
```

There is output shown in the terminal, but appently directly from the the `rsnapshot` command, and none appears stored in the variable `rsnapshotresult`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$( ... )` captures *stdout* only, and stdout is intended to contain only a program's result. Informational, error, prompt, and status messages should be written to stderr (and password prompts historically/typically bypass both and go straight to the TTY).

Comment: BTW, in general, avoid `[ $? -ne 0 ]`. Consider instead `if ! rsnapshot_output=$(rsnapshot -v daily 2>&1); then printf '%s\n' "rsnapshotdaily.sh error" "$rsnapshot_output" "done" >&2; fi`, branching directly on exit status rather than needing to refer back to it -- this is much

Comment: (Also, avoid `echo $foo`, which munges whitespace/newlines/wildcards/etc as described in [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo); always use `echo "$foo"` to emit content in a variable -- or, even better, `printf '%s\n' "$foo"`).

Comment: Thanks guys, that cleared it up! The issue is indeed the one addressed in the question that mine is marked a duplicate of.